# how do i preload a hashmap in an object(without put method)?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a class and it has a couple data structures in it among which is a hashmap. But I want the hashmap to have default values so I need to preload it. How do I do this since I can't use put method inside the object?

```
class Profile
{
    HashMap closedAges = new HashMap();
    closedAges.put("19");
}
```

I fixed it with this but I had to use a method within the object.

```
class Profile
{   
    HashMap closedAges = loadAges();
    HashMap loadAges()
    {
        HashMap closedAges = new HashMap();

        String[] ages = {"19", "46", "54", "56", "83"};
        for (String age : ages)
        {
            closedAges.put(age, false);
        }
        return closedAges;
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't you use the hashmap methods?

Comment: What does the code look like right now, and what have you tried to get what you want?

Comment: Why can't you use the put() method? I don't follow that part.

Comment: @Todd I was doing it outside of a method since I wanted to initialize a HashMap right away like you can do with a string array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
   put("1", "one");
   put("2", "two");
   put("3", "three");
}};
```

This java idiom is called [*double brace initialization*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization).:

> The first brace creates a new AnonymousInnerClass, the second declares an instance initializer block that is run when the anonymous inner class is instantiated.

Comment: Wow it works, thanks. Can you explain why and how it works? I've never seen double brackets before especially inside a variable declaration.

Answer (score 12):

You want to do this in the constructor of your class, for instance

```
class Example {

   Map<Integer, String> data = new HashMap<>();

   public Example() {
      data.put(1, "Hello");
      data.put(2, "World");
   }
}
```

or to use the freakish double brace initialization feature of Java:

```
class Example {

   Map<Integer, String> data;

   public Example() {
        /* here the generic type parameters cannot be omitted */
        data = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
           put(1, "Hello");
           put(2, "World");
      }};
   }
}
```

And finally, if your `HashMap` is a static field of your class, you can perform the initialization inside a `static` block:

```
static {

   data.put(1, "Hello");
   ...
}
```

---

In order to address Behes comment, if you are not using Java 7, fill the `<>` brackets with your type parameters, in this case `<Integer, String>`.

Comment: @Behe Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: Aren't you missing type parameters?

Comment: @Behe - Omitting the generic types in the instantiation is a new feature in Java 7.

Comment: Then I have to rephrase my comment: That won't work this way without Java 7.

Comment: For double brace you can use just put instead of data.put.

Comment: The IDE will probably also show a warning for not declaring a serialVersionUID when using double brace initialization. (one reason i stopped using it ;))